# insert images with no vertical distance in (la-)tex

Tags: image, latex, tex

I'm trying this, but I get a little distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}

 \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}

\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}

\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}


\end{document}
```

Comment: With the help from fschmitt I remembered the '*'.
with a \vspace*{-1pt} between the rows the images align also vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\hspace*{-1pt}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}\hspace*{-1pt}\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{1.png}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast, but you are only handling the horizontal space. That already aligns with no distance.
My Problem is that the vertical (line) space is not zero.

Comment: Hmm. This is strange. I tested it and got a 1 pixel horizontal space but no vertical spacing.